# Question about data_collator throwing a key error in Hugging face

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to use data_collator function in hugging face using this code:

```
datasets = dataset.train_test_split(test_size=0.1)
train_dataset = datasets["train"]
val_dataset = datasets["test"]

print(type(train_dataset))

def data_collator(data):
# Initialize lists to store pixel values and input ids
   pixel_values_list = []
   input_ids_list = []

# Iterate over each sample in the data
   for item in data:      
      pixel_values_list.append(torch.tensor(item["pixel_values"]))
      input_ids_list.append(torch.tensor(item["input_ids"]))


return {
    "pixel_values": torch.stack(pixel_values_list),
    "labels": torch.stack(input_ids_list)
}
```

the train_data has 5 keys including input_ids. However, when I print(data[0]) inside the data_collator function, I only see 1 key, which is giving an error when running the trainer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "caption-code.py", line 134, in <module>
trainer.train()
  File "C:\Users\moham\anaconda3\envs\transformer\lib\site- 
 packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 1321, in train
ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
 File "C:\Users\moham\anaconda3\envs\transformer\lib\site- 
  packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 1528, in _inner_training_loop
  for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
    File "C:\Users\moham\anaconda3\envs\transformer\lib\site- 
  packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
  data = self._next_data()
 File "C:\Users\moham\anaconda3\envs\transformer\lib\site- 
  packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 561, in _next_data
data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
 File "C:\Users\moham\anaconda3\envs\transformer\lib\site- 
 packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 52, in fetch
 return self.collate_fn(data)
 File "caption-code.py", line 102, in data_collator
 input_ids_list.append(item["input_ids"])
  KeyError: 'input_ids'
```

I am using the trainer function as follow:

```
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
predict_with_generate=True,
evaluation_strategy="epoch",
per_device_train_batch_size=4,
per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
output_dir="C:/Users/moham/Desktop/Euler/output",
logging_dir="./logs",
logging_steps=10,
save_steps=10,
eval_steps=10,
warmup_steps=10,
max_steps=100,  # adjust as needed
overwrite_output_dir=True,
save_total_limit=3,
 )
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
model=model,
args=training_args,
train_dataset=train_dataset,
eval_dataset=val_dataset,
data_collator=data_collator,
tokenizer=tokenizer,
compute_metrics=compute_exact_match
 )
trainer.train()
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your `train_dataset` which I assume is the `data` in your `data_collator(data)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue is in your `Seq2SeqTrainingArguments` which is leading the error in your `data_collator()`.

**Reason:** The `.trainer()` is by default removing any unknown columns from your data when you are providing a custom `data_collator()`. As a result even though each sample in your `train_dataset` has all the keys, when you send that to `data_collator()`, the `.trainer()` automatically removes the unknown columns.

**Solution:** You need to include an argument in your training arguments like the following:

```
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
predict_with_generate=True,
remove_unused_columns=False, 
...)
```

The `remove_unused_columns=False,` would prevent the default behaviour and you'd get the entire data in `data_collator()`. This [issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/7823) would be useful for further reference.

Comment: a sample of the train_dataset[0]:
{'image_path': 'C:/..../211.jpg', 'caption': A penguin…..;"', 'input_ids': [1, 9197, 7203, 1, 32, 1, 15341, 9197, 7203, 1, 33, 1, 15341, 9197, 7203, 1,……..], 'attention_mask': [1, 1, …… 0], 'pixel_values': [[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1…]]]

Comment: Thank you for sharing the sample data. It was really helpful to reproduce the error and understand what was actually happening. Please ignore the previous statement. I updated my answer and this should at least help you to get rid of the current error you're facing.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you, now this makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Sure, happy to help!